# Using dc.js with node.js

Tags: node.js, dc.js

Is it possible to use dc.js with node.js, and if so how? I would like to provide an example, but it's hard to see how to start on this, and no working examples seem to be available online.

Comment: `dc.js` is a front end SVG rendering library. What are you trying to achieve by running it with node.js?

Comment: I want to visualise data from a server-side MongoDB. Is this the way to do it, or is there a better option?

Comment: @MaVe You might be better off running `dc.js` within PhantomJS.  You can control this from Node.js.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the idea. Is there any documentation or an example available on how to do this? I'm new to both node.js and dc.js, so that would be very helpful.

Comment: @MaVe The PhantomJS docs are pretty solid and concise.  I'd recommend starting there.  http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Answer (score 3):

In short, yes.
I have implemented a full fledged app using nodejs and dc while the document store was mongo. The nodejs server is used for fetching the data from mongo db and serving it as api. Dc.js then uses this data for rendering charts.

I will write a blog post about it and post it in a couple of days. In the meantime do let me know if you have any more queries.

**Updated:**
Here is the link to the blog post.Do share if you find it useful.
https://anmolkoul.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/interactive-data-visualization-using-d3-js-dc-js-nodejs-and-mongodb/