# Is it possible to run dc.js on the server side using node.js?

Tags: node.js, dc.js, server-side-rendering

There is another question just like that: [Using dc.js with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362586/using-dc-js-with-node-js)

But the example in the answer uses dc.js on the client side. I want to use it in the server side.

I created a .js file and I put this line:

```
const dc = require('dc');
```

When I execute the file I get this error:

/home/fagner/projects/node-test/node_modules/dc/dc.js:475
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
^

ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at _dc (/home/fagner/projects/node-test/node_modules/dc/dc.js:475:1)
    at /home/fagner/projects/node-test/node_modules/dc/dc.js:13649:26
    at Object. (/home/fagner/projects/node-test/node_modules/dc/dc.js:13654:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)

What am I missing?

There are many questions related to this on StackOverflow, but it seems that everyone can import dc.js without any problem. Do I need to install any other dependency?

I know that Element is not recognized by the server, so how can I mock it using domino?

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried it, and it is about 5 years old, but someone contributed this simple library:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc-node

which wraps dc for node and brings in DOM emulation.

It uses jsdom - you may be right that domino is a better choice today.

If you do fix it up, please consider making a pull request!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. When I looked to the offending code block in `dc.js:475:1`, I have found that it starts with the comment

```
    // polyfill for IE
    // from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches#Polyfill
```

So, it looks, it is written for compatibility with IE. I commented the block and after that the module has been loaded with `requre('dc')` without problems.

Comment: Thanks @victor, I [opened an issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1535) to track this. I'm still confused, though - how could you run dc without `Element`? dc is all about manipulating the DOM, so you need some DOM emulation, right?

Comment: @Gordon, you are right. But I am just starting to play with that module. If I find how to do that, i will write a comment.

Comment: dc-node uses jsdom for DOM emulation but it sounds like Domino is more current. I would think you would need to load one of those packages before loading dc, or at least before you try to instantiate anything in dc. Unfortunately I don't have experience myself.

Comment: @Gordon: Probably, yes. Thank you for your advice